# Why didn't Picard borrow a Klingon vessel to go to Nelvana III?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode "[The Defector](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Defector_(episode))," the *Enterprise* flies into the Neutral Zone to investigate a secret base being built by the Romulans on the planet Nelvana III, based on information given by the defector Admiral Jarok.

Picard is expecting

> "swift and heavy resistance"

and they swiftly run into two Warbirds that decloak and threaten to destroy the *Enterprise-D* and her crew. Luckily three Klingon vessels then decloak behind the *Enterprise-D* and save the day.

Is there an **in-universe reason** why Picard didn't simply borrow a Klingon vessel to go to Nelvana III under cloak, do reconnaissance, then fly out of the Neutral Zone (undetected) rather than going in with the *Enterprise-D*?

Comment: Um...'Yes'?  Really, you're asking a one-word-answerable question.  Perhaps rephrase it to ask for reasons Picard may have wanted to use the *Enterprise*?

Comment: To nitpick, that would be Nelvana 3 or Nelvana III, not Nelvana 111.

Comment: It was all done so you could enjoy this exchange between Picard and Tomalak: 
     TOMALAK
   Captain Picard, I urge you.
   Surrender. Consider the men and
   women you would lead into a lost
   cause.

     PICARD
   If the cause is just and
   honorable, they are prepared to
   give their lives. Are you
   prepared to die today, Tomalak?

     TOMALAK
   I expected more from you than an
   idle threat, Picard.

     PICARD
   And so you shall have it. Now,
   Mister Worf...

Comment: @Morgan - Agreed. Also you need to take into account Roddenberry's quote about how "our heroes don't sneak around".

Comment: @Richard - If our heroes don't sneak then why did they ask for a cloaked ship to find Spock in reunification?

Comment: @user16416 - Erm, because Star Trek is wildly inconsistent and frequently makes no sense?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less speculative

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Picard believes in effective responses to situations.

So the Romulans are constructing a secret base somewhere. It can either be confirmed under cloak, reported to Starfleet Intelligence, allowed to enter the same circuit of informational subterfuge which Romulans show time and again to have an extreme affinity and appreciation for...

Or, quite separately, Picard can leverage his good standing with the Klingon Empire -- a mutual adversary to the Romulans -- to display a willingness to investigate the plot out in the open, to stare Tomalok in the face and call out the attempted deceit, and when prompted to flex, do so with a bunch of angry Klingons in the background.

He's posturing, yes, but he's also showcasing that he doesn't have to play sneaky Romulan games to get after what he needs. One thing Romulans just seem to despise (and who doesn't -- but Romulans, more so) is being outwitted. It isn't enough to just gain the information; the information is a McGuffin, the spy game is paramount. It's the old 'you saw him, he had a gun' routine; they create a situation to which the Federation must respond, only to call them out for a treaty violation and respond with 'I was acting in self-defense', while giving the Romulan Empire full rights to declare war. Picard throws all that away; he takes the flagship of the Federation into the Neutral Zone, leveraging his violation of treaty against their own, and then his Klingon friends decloak and he sends Tomalok back to Romulus with his "u mad bro" face on.

Comment: It's a wonder the border outposts didn't detect anything

Answer (score 5):

It may not have made more sense, actually. Chances are good that the the Romulans were monitoring the Enterprise ever since the defector boarded the ship. For the Enterprise to suddenly head off towards Klingon space, rendezvous with a Klingon ship, and then wander off somewhere and look like it wasn't going to follow up on the planted information would have appeared mighty suspicious.

Romulans, given the chance, will choose to not appear as an aggressor. They *would* be happy to destroy the Enterprise over a seemingly unprovoked breach of the neutral zone, to protect their territory from Federation aggression. Once the Birds of Prey uncloaked, however, they could no longer be sure of their deception being kept from the Federation.

Comment: The Enterprise didn't really have to rendezvous with a Klingon ship, just send a communique to Klingon high command to send some ships in.

Comment: @user16416 That is what they did. The Klingon ships met up with the Enterprise at Nelvana III.

Comment: what I was meaning the Klingon ships go in by themselves under cloak,do some recon and report to the Enterprise while it stays in Fed space.